# Group by month with rollup when date is yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, rollup

I'm doing an online course in SQL and I need to have date in yyyy-mm-dd format. I need to group by month to show total sales of medalId and total medalId sold in a month.

I just can't seem to be able to engineer a way to rollup with month using this format. Any advice and guidance would be really appreciated:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(medalId) AS totalProducts, SUM(medalId) as totalSales
from orders
GROUP BY date WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: have you set the date type data for that format in the table?

Comment: A `date` does not have a format, because when a date is formatted (like `yyyy-mm-dd`), it becomes a string.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has the `DATE` datatype for columns. Use it. Take the trouble to avoid using `VARCHAR()` or `CHAR()` columns to hold dates. It's worth it because you get a lot of cool date arithmetic when you do that. Also, they sort correctly.  Your `2020-03-25` format is compatible with the `DATE` datatype.

You want something like this, using the [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) date-arithmetic function.

```sql
SELECT LAST_DAY(date) month_ending, 
       COUNT(medalId) AS totalProducts, SUM(medalId) as totalSales
from orders
GROUP BY LAST_DAY(date) WITH ROLLUP;
```

**Pro tip**: When doing database programming, it is worth your time to learn your DBMS's [date/time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and [string processing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) functions.